# Elastic Collisions in Unity 2D

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics, vector, rigidbody

I am trying to create elastic collisions in 2d game in unity. I have a ball surrounded with a polygon collider and im calculating the reflected vector using the ball velocity and the normal at the contact point. The whole thing works find but I have a slight issue where the ball gets stuck when sometimes.As you can see below the ball does bounce but later on it comes to a stop

Here are some details on the implementation.

The ball is a circle collider and ive drawn the object using a line renderer and ive added a polygon collider to it by using the width of the line. The polygon collider consists of about 130 points.

The ball has its collision detection mode set to continuous but using discreet mode doesn't work either.

The speed of the ball is not the problem because I face the same issue even if I move the ball at lower speeds. I'm using Vector3.AddForce to move the ball. The force mode is ForceMode.Impulse.

Any help will bee greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Below you can find the code.

```cs
    void Start()
    {
    rb = Transfrom.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
    velocity = rb.velocity;
    }

        private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
        {

            float speed = velocity.magnitude;
            Vector3 direction = Vector3.Reflect(velocity.normalized, collision.contacts[0].normal);
            rb.velocity = direction * speed;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
    velocity = rb.velocity;
    }
```

[image: Elastic Collision Problem]

Comment: It looks like you neglected to update your velocity variable after reflecting it.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add in thee question. I'm updating the velocity variable in the Update() method

Comment: That could be part of it. You're not guaranteed to get an Update in between two collisions — particularly when your object wedges itself into a narrow corner like we see in this gif.

Comment: What do you suggest should I do. I can manipulate the magnitude but by normalization but  if I change the velocity vector then I risk changing the direction in which the ball will move. I even tried to drop all physics and just use recasts but that didnt work either.